# Match two equal-sized data.frames and then filter results on a third

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have the following three `data.frame`:

```
area1 <- data.frame(ua = c(1, 2, 3),
                   sub_ua1 = c(0, 100, 0),
                   sub_ua2 = c(100, 100, 100),
                   sub_ua3 = c(100, 0, 0))

area2 <- data.frame(ua = c(1, 2, 3),
                    sub_ua1 = c(100, 100, 0),
                    sub_ua2 = c(100, 100, 0),
                    sub_ua3 = c(100, 0, 0))

df <- data.frame(ua = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 4), rep(3, 7)),
                 subua = c(rep("sub_ua1", 3), "sub_ua2", "sub_ua3",
                           "sub_ua1", "sub_ua1", "sub_ua2", "sub_ua3",
                           "sub_ua1", c(rep("sub_ua2", 2)), rep("sub_ua3", 4)),
                 value = c(rep(2, 3), rep(4, 3), rep(2, 2), rep(1, 8)))
```

What I'm trying to do is, based on column `ua` in dfs `area_1` and `area_2`, filter only `sub_ua` (1 to 3) that have a match of 100 in each df. For example, the first value of `sub_ua2` is 100 in both `area_1` and `area_2`. This is a "sub_ua" I want.

Then, after having this list of "sub_ua" per "ua", filter only them on `df` to obtain the filtered `value`.

The results should be:
For `ua` == 1, get both `sub_ua2` and `sub_ua3`
For `ua` == 2, get both `sub_ua1` and `sub_ua2`
For `ua` == 3, get `sub_ua2`

EDIT:

I was using the following approach to obtain a `data.frame` of rows and columns indices:

```
library(prodlim)
# Indices for data frame 1 and 2 for values = 100
indices_1 <- which(area1 == 100, arr.ind = TRUE)
indices_2 <- which(area2 == 100, arr.ind = TRUE)

# Rows where indices are matched between the two data frame indices
indices_rows <- na.omit(row.match(as.data.frame(indices_1), as.data.frame(indices_2)))

# Row-column indices where both data frames have values of 100
indices_2[indices_rows, ]
```

I just don't know how to use this to filter in the final dataset `df`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly this should work:

```
area1 <- data.frame(ua = c(1, 2, 3),
                    sub_ua1 = c(0, 100, 0),
                    sub_ua2 = c(100, 100, 100),
                    sub_ua3 = c(100, 0, 0))

area2 <- data.frame(ua = c(1, 2, 3),
                    sub_ua1 = c(100, 100, 0),
                    sub_ua2 = c(100, 100, 0),
                    sub_ua3 = c(100, 0, 0))
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

area1 %>% 
  left_join(area2, by = "ua", suffix = c(".area1",".area2")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -ua,names_to = "var",values_to = "value") %>% 
  separate(col = var,into = c("var","area"),sep = "\\.") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = area,values_from = value) %>% 
  filter(area1 == 100, area2 == 100) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("area"))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ua var    
  <dbl> <chr>  
1     1 sub_ua2
2     1 sub_ua3
3     2 sub_ua1
4     2 sub_ua2
```